# How can I make this Google Sheets formula more simple?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(B3,C3), COUNTIF(B4,C4), COUNTIF(B5,C5), COUNTIF(B6,C6), COUNTIF(B7,C7), COUNTIF(B8,C8), COUNTIF(B9,C9), COUNTIF(B10,C10), COUNTIF(B11,C11), COUNTIF(B12,C12), COUNTIF(B13,C13), COUNTIF(B14,C14), COUNTIF(B15,C15), COUNTIF(B16,C16), COUNTIF(B17,C17), COUNTIF(B18,C18), COUNTIF(B19,C19), COUNTIF(B20,C20), COUNTIF(B21,C21), COUNTIF(B22,C22))/20*100
```

I'm attempting to match values between two columns and show the percentage that match. The ugly part is having to do a COUNTIF for each column comparison manually. Is there a way to just match B3:B22 against all of C3:C22 and get the count? My understanding of Google Sheets formulas is limited. Any help is appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B22=C3:C22,1,0)))/20*100
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you. I need to learn how to use ARRAYFORMULA I guess :-)

Comment: Optimized version - ```=ArrayFormula(SUM((B3:B22=C3:C22)/ROWS(B3:C22)*100))```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(1*(B3:B22=C3:C22))/20*100)
```

Comment: Returns the wrong value :-(

Comment: @JeredOdegard answer updated

Answer (score 0):

I'd think just a sumproduct would be simplest, no?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B22=C3:C22)*5)
```